# Ubuntu: understanding iptables rules to allow domain name lookup

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, iptables

I'm currently setting up iptables rules on my web server (Ubuntu 18.04). Almost everything works as I expect it to work, but for the rules applied to DN lookup queries.
Here is my understanding:

- DN lookup requests are sent to the port 53 of DN servers (by default)
- DN lookup requests can happen over both TCP and UDP protocols

Therefore, I set up the following rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

In other words, accept any incoming connections coming from the port 53 (supposing they are responses for the DN queries my server will send to the port 53).
However, this doesn't work. A *nslookup ubuntuforums.org* command times out. And here is the part I'm not getting: if I add the iptables rules below, then it works

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

If I'm reading the above correctly, it means that I'm accepting incoming connections sent to the port 53 of my server. I don't understand why this is needed.
I used tcpdump to see what is going on when I run *nslookup ubuntuforums.org* and I can't see any connections sent to the port 53 of my machine.
There is obviously something I'm missing but I don't know what... Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Original post on ubuntuforums.org: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2409812

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your server has at least 2 interfaces: the local loopback and the ethernet interface.

The way you apply your rules, they apply to both interfaces.

When one makes a DNS query, for a long time, it was going directly through the ethernet interface (or whatever is used by the route used to reach the DNS servers).
But this is going only through the `OUTPUT` chain, and not `INPUT` (and [a few others not relevant here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Networks/IP_Tables#/media/File:Diagrama_linux_netfilter_iptables.png)).

Recently, distributions start to ship local DNS caching systems (`dnsmasq`, `systemd-resolved`, ...).

Using Ubuntu 18.04, you have the latest systemd features.
Therefore I suspect that you have `systemd-resolved` using the loopback interface to provide DNS caching.
When you use `nslookup`, it's not going directly to the servers specified in your `/etc/resolv.conf`, but goes through `systemd-resolved` first.

In order to allow this, you need to add firewall rules allowing INPUT traffic on the port 53 for the loopback interface.

My recommendation would be to just whitelist all traffic for the loopback interface using `iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: Awesome, right on spot! I allowed all traffic on the loopback interface, removed all the iptables rules I had with the port 53 set as source and destination port and confirmed that everything works correctly. Thank you very much for your help, everything is crystal clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

The flags `--dport --sport` are respectively `Source Port` and `Destination Port`;

Source port is the port from where the connection start, a request to port 53 could start from port `55231`, for example if your server perform a DNS query it's target port will be the port 53 but the source port not. As per your example that you says it is not work it is because of this reason, the request source port is not 53, so iptables do it's job.

Instead the destination port will filter packets for the destination port so a request sent to port 53 will accepted, and does not meter from which port or host (based on your example).

In conclusion yes, you are now permitting query to port 53 of your server, you do not see any connection to port 53 when you run the `nslookup` probably because the query is sent to the remote server configured in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Some additional information: there are no rules rejecting outgoing traffic from my server; in other words, my server can send requests with no restrictions at all. Plus, I have a rule that allows incoming traffic for any established connections. Therefore, the only thing to authorize should be incoming traffic with 53 as source port shouldn't it?

Comment: generally you should never receive requests starts from port 53 remotely, which entry do you have in your resolve.conf file? Is it there any nameserver point in to loopback interface?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why I shouldn't receive any traffic coming from the port 53 of the remote. Since that's the destination port of my outgoing requests, I expect it to also be the source port of the incoming response. I double-checked it with tcpdump and it seems to be what's happening. Am I misreading what I see in tcpdump or something?

In my /etc/resolve.conf, there is only one entry, which is the IP address of my DNS 

Comment: the behavior you describe it is really strange, I just test out on my computer, when I DROP the destination port 53 in the INPUT chain every think works, instead not working when I DROP the source port 53. So your conclusion are right, but I do not understand why you have to keep open the request to your server with port destination 53, that should be enabled only if you have a DNS server installed.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my assumptions  I can't understand either why I need to accept incoming traffic to the port 53 of my machine  I'll keep searching and update if I find anything.